# Entity Framework throws error: Invalid object name

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm getting the following error with this sample I received, it looks correct by the manuals and docs I found.

There are a lot of books I found here and all looks have the same pattern of code that looks like this one I received from a friend last week.

I don't have much more detail about it but this form keep telling me its looks like mostly code then I need keep typing.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   HResult=0x80131904
>   Message=Invalid object name 'Persons'.
>   Source=Core .Net SqlClient Data Provider

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public class BaseModel : DbContext
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var strCnn = @"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TutorialDB;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(strCnn);
        }
    }
}

----------------

using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ConsoleApp.Model
{
    public class Person : BaseModel
    {
        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }

        public Person() {}

        public Person(int _id, string _name) {
            this.Id = _id;
            this.Name = _name;
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

----------------

using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (Model.Person p = new Model.Person()) 
            {
                p.Persons.Add(new Model.Person(01, "Name001"));
                _ = p.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: the error is saying that ```persons``` most likely an table name is not existing

Comment: where do you found a tutorial that tells you that every entity should be inherited from DbContext? This is absolutely wrong.

Comment: Please share your table structure. Most likely your table `person` is missing. Please check again in your database for same.

Comment: The code above is completely wrong

Comment: @mark, please read and try the [getting started guide with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/full-dotnet/new-db). I think it should only take at most 15 minutes and will really help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As a wild stab in the dark, I'd say you havent actually added the configuration for the entities anywhere. You either need annotations of use the fluent configuration to tell EF where to look for things. Like this: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configuration-in-entity-framework-core.aspx